# How can i get multiple div's on a single page in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Iam trying to build an online shopping website i want multiple items to be displayed on the front end in react js iam using bootstrap library as css. Below is my return div how can i get multiple items on a single page.

```
return (
  <div className= "App"> 
    <img src={shotgun} className="App-logo" alt="logo"></img>
    <button onClick = {this.handleIncrement} className = "btn btn-info m-2">+</button>
    <span className = {this.getBadgeColor()} >{this.countFormat()}</span>
    <button onClick = {this.handleDecrement} className = "btn btn-danger m-2">-</button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking but if you want to stack divs side by side you need to use Fragments:

```js
 <React.Fragment>
      <div />
      <div />
      <div />
</React.Fragment>
```

[React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Otherwise what your generally going to want to do is create another component above this one, and import/render as many of these as needed into the above component. Hope that makes sense.